# Find out where DLL is coming from in Visual Studio build.

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, reference, dependencies

I'm seeing a DLL file appear in my build's bin folder when building from Visual Studio, but I'm unsure of where it is coming from. The DLL is Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll. My project does reference Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll, so my original thought was that it was being copied as some sort of dependency. However, I've seen the same code built on another machine, and the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll file is not copied into the bin. Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: Enable MSBBuild diagnostic logging and then perform a string search.

Answer (score 3):

Check if **Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll** is registered in GAC.

- Click Start --> Run
- Type "Assembly" and hit enter
- Check if Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll file is present.

This file may be in GAC on the machines where it does not gets copied to bin automatically. Whereas on your machine, I doubt this file is not in GAC.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I only have the following folders present in C:/Windows/assembly: GAC, GAC_32, GAC_64, GAC_MSIL, NativeImages (4 folders with different versions), temp, and tmp. However, a folder named "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" which contains 4 different versions of that dll are present within the GAC_MSIL folder. If I should be seeing it in the "assembly" folder, how do you go about properly installing it into that location?

Comment: Try installing DLL in GAC using following command
**gacutil -i Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll.** Refer (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79(v=vs.100).aspx)